# Exoplayer Custom Renderer For Images

Tags: exoplayer2.x, android-mediacodec

I am trying to create an ImageRenderer for Exoplayer. I'm not sure how to start and am struggling to understand all of the components needed. My use case is I would like to have a playlist that could be a mix of hls and png url sources. I'm playing the Hls videos perfectly find but get 403 download errors with the pngs (as expected). I'm assuming I need a custom MediaSource and DataSource for the pngs as well? I'm getting really confused with possibly needing a custom MediaPeriod and SampleStream as well and it's one big jumble. I feel like this should be relatively simple to create the bitmap from the png stream and renderer it to a SurfaceView.

Comment: How you have managed this?